# Spec Has No Expectations error on Angular 2 templateUrl

Tags: jasmine, angular

I have a angular 2 Component MyComp

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myform',
    templateUrl: './myform.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

This is my spec.

```
it('should work', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(MyComp).then((fixture) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(1+ 1).toEqual(2);
    });
}));
```

When i execute the tests its giving me an error

```
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known native property
```

The actual code works, but its only the tests that are failing,

**Update :**
Spec works if i replace templateUrl with template.
i.e if i just try with

template: `<h1>Fake</h1> <ul> <li *ngFor="#item of items"> </li> </ul>`

Interested to know if anyone has tested components with templateUrl with angular 2.0 beta version.

Thanks !

Comment: There's a bug when using templateUrl with unit tests (check [issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5662)). For now just use `template` property or `overrideTemplate`.

Comment: If i use overrideTemplate,would i be still testing the actual component ? or just a dummy component ?

Comment: It would be the actual component with the template overriden, so it's basically the same. You can still use `template` property if you're unsure.

Answer (score 2):

You should add [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html) or [`CORE_DIRECTIVES`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/CORE_DIRECTIVES-let.html) to the component **directives**:

```ts
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'myform',
  templateUrl: './myform.html',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES] // <- HERE!!!
})
export class MyForm { /* ... */ }
```

or

```ts
import { NgFor } from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'myform',
  templateUrl: './myform.html',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgFor] // <- HERE!!!
})
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried to add an error handler to tcb.createAsync and the actual error its showing is TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExpectationResult' of undefined
    at Env.fail (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:987:24)
    at next.fail (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1903:19)

Comment: @user636525 Hmm, actually I have no idea about this error :(

Comment: I think the issue is with templateUrl with @Component directive. If i replace templateUrl with just template:`<h1> Fake </h1>` , it's working fine. Have you tried component testing with templateUrl instead of template ?